# Python selenium webdriver find_element_by_android_uiautomator() alternative

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is there an alternative for deprecated selenium-webdriver method:

```
find_element_by_android_uiautomator()
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using:

```
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy
self.driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, '')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).